# Question about specific linear operator that does not have inverse.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{R}[x]$ = the set of real polynomials, and let $f(x) = d/dx$. Then what is $g(x)$ so that $f(g(x))$ is identity (but $g(f(x))$ is not)? Sorry my calculus is a  little rusty. I considered setting $g(x)$ to be the indefinite integral but that's not a function because it doesn't have a definite value.

I remember something called the antiderivative - is that the same as indefinite integral? Obviously definite integral wouldn't work.

Comment: Your $f$ is the $\frac{d}{dx}$ operator, and $f$ sends $x^n$ to $nx^{n-1}$ for $n>0$ and sends $1$ to $0$. Then $g$ should be the $\int$ operator which sends $x^n$ to $\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$ (the integration constant must be taken to be zero for $g$ to be a linear map). Now the point is that if I tell you what polynomial I have _after_ I applied $\frac{d}{dx}$, you can't tell me what polynomial I started with. You can't guess my constant term, because there is nothing left of it. That's because $\frac{d}{dx}$ sends the standard basis vector $1$ to $0$. Hence $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Therefore $g\circ f$, first applying differentiation $f$ and then antiderivative (integration) $g$, is not the identity map. It is the linear map that annihilates the constant term. On the other hand $f\circ g = I$, the identity map. So $g$ is injective and $f$ is surjective, as mappings from $\mathbb{R}[x]$ to $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

When you take the antiderivative, you have to add a constant.  The derivative of the antiderivative is certainly the identity (because the constant goes away). But the antiderivative of the derivative adds that constant back in, so it may not be the identity.

As Andres points out below, for the operator to be linear, we need to take $C=0$.

For example:
$$
f\circ g(x+1)=f\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+x\right)=x+1
\\g\circ f(x+1)=g(1)=x+0=x
$$

Comment: Yes I know this but my concern is that the antiderivative would not qualify as a function (and hence not a linear operator) because for each polynomial it takes on infinite values depending on c.

Comment: Pick whatever $C$ you'd like! Then it's as much a function as $d/dx$ is.

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks!

Comment: In fact, pick $C=0$, since you probably want a *linear* operator.

Comment: @Andres is quite right. I'll adjust my answer to reflect this.